# How to manipulate the application that I launched from my application

Tags: java, android, swift, background-process

I've been searching about this topic recently. I have read about `how to launch an application via`onClick`in my original application`.

However, I'd just like to ask on how could I **manipulate** the launched app.

For **instance**, I pressed my app's button and it launched `Facebook`. How can I **access Facebook's** `text box` and `button` to **post a status**?

Could everything also be done on the `background thread`?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Fortunately, you can't in general, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare was expecting that mobile development has its _'Selenium Web Driver'_.. Anyways, thanks for the enlightenment! :)

Comment: There is the equivalent of Selenium, in the form of things like UiAutomator. However, that only works for testing, just as AFAIK Selenium only works for testing.

Comment: You should probably use Facebook's API rather than trying to force actions to occur between apps. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Intents.

Intents could be handled by many apps.
So if there isn't a special facebook intent (which can only be served by the facebook app) the user is free to choose which app shall be opened to handle the intent.

The intent should look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CREATE_FACEBOOK_POST);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my facebook post.");
```

Comment: I am able to jump to a Facebook intent **but** how would I be able to **trigger** the `text box and button` in that intent?

Comment: I added a could-be intent.

Comment: Cool but is it possible to perform a `button click` after that? I'm not sure on how we could find the `id` of elements in mobile apps like the `F12` function that we could use in Google Chrome..

Comment: You do not click. Also you do not type anything. You ask if there is an app on your mobile device that can handle your Intent. If there is exactly one app, this will fullfill your intent automatically. If there are more than one app, the user can choose which app to use. So if you create a "Facebook"-intent you give your data to your facebook app and that is doing something with it - hopefully it will create a facebook post (with an intent like the given one).